# Get key value pair from JSON string without using json.net

Tags: c#, json, key-value, javascriptserializer

I would like to create a key value pair from a json string :

```
string json = "[{\"Job\": \"Step\",\"Id\": \"D:\\\\file.CATPart\",\"Source\": \"V5\"},{\"Job\": \"Step\",\"Id\": \"D:\\\\file1.CATPart\",\"Source\": \"V5\"}]";

var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Arguments>>(json);

foreach (var obj in jsonObj)
        {
            jobtype = obj.Job;
            SelectedId = obj.Id;
            source = obj.Source;    }
```

I am currently deserializing to a list, but want it to be  akey value pair to avoid issues as to addition of more parameters, etc. How can i do it without usin json.net or any othere external dll?

Comment: If you don't want to use an external library, you have to write your own.

Comment: Using Dictionary?

Comment: @MarcoDalZovo yes

Comment: I don't understand your problem so... You can switch to a Dictionary and use it to deserialize your Json string. I got this or You need to achieve something else?

Comment: @MarcoDalZovo you mean use dictionary in place of List? I tried this: var jsonObj1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
            foreach (var obj1 in jsonObj1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj1.Key + ":" + obj1.Value);
            }
But get an InvalidOperationException

Comment: Actually You need a List of Dictionaries because Json is an array

Comment: If you want to earn experience and learn deeply then of course try it, but if it is not the case then you are trying to reinvent something easy to access, it is like reinventing spoon to eat the soup.

Comment: @MarcoDalZovo Thanks that ( List of Dictionaries ) did give me the expected result!

Answer (score 0):

As said by @marsze you have to write your own `deserializer`.
You can use a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` to store your parameters.

Answer (score -1):

A bad solution would be to process the string manually, by iterating through the lines, then use string.split(':'). Then you can clean away all the none- letter and digits with regex, and insert it into an enumerable of your choice. Remember to handle nesting and arrays with care, (unit test this like crazy).

Would be resource intensive, but it will do the job. And cost two weeks of dev-time to properly implement and test.

Or you can copy code from GitHub repos that already have some nice solution to handle this. Decompile Newtonsoft maybe?